# Click anywhere else to hide js p5

Tags: p5.js

Using **js p5**
trying to make an **ellipse** that when i click on it I get a **small window** with som data or text in it, and i want to be able to **hide** this **small window** when i click anywhere else this **small window**.
Somthing like when you press on a place on **google maps** and you get place information, and when you click anywhere else this infromation window get hided, så you can try to click on another place.

I want to get this using JS P5

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think a way you could do this. You could create an object, call it whatever, and have an x and y variable in it (like this.x and this.y i cant think of the name rn) and a clicked variable that will be true or false. outside of the main draw loop you can use the function mousePressed and write something like this:

```
function mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX > this.x - [the width of the ellipse / 2] && mousex < this.x + [width of ellipse / 2] && mouseY > this.y - [height of the ellipse / 2] && mouseY < this.y + [height of ellipse / 2]) {
    if (!ellipse.clicked) {
      ellipse.clikced = true;
    }
  } else {
    ellipse.clicked = false;
  }
}
```

(excuse the length of the if statement its just checking around the ellipse if im correct)
you could have a for loop if you want multiple
and then have something like this in a function called display inside of the object

```
display() {
  ellipse(this.x, this.y, [width], [lenght]);
  // placeholder for the menu
  if (this.clicked) {
    rect(this.x, this.y, 30, 50);
  }
}
```

or something of the sort.

i hope this works and has helped you out!

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try this.

Comment: It didn't work, i think i didn't know how to write this code, am new in p5.

Comment: what did i miss
https://editor.p5js.org/saliem_antoun/sketches/ap70zVdsi

Comment: yeah no problem. sorry i didnt see the other comments but happy i could help